# Asp.Net Core 2.2 Cookie Authentication in micro-service architecture

Tags: asp.net-core, event-handling, session-cookies, redirect, cookie-authentication

I have 2 services, one web frontend and another backend. Authentication is done at the backed which includes JWT, Cookie, Session, etc. How does the `CookieAuthenticationEvents` work in this case, particularly with regards to `OnRedirect<foo>`? Are they web frontend-related events? How would the backed convey the `OnRedirect<foo>` back to the frontend service and then back to the client browser to redirect to the designated URL?